# Adding an index to a MongoDB collection hash field

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoid

I have a MongoDB collection that I would like to add an index on. For the purpose of this post, let's say the collection name is `Cats`. I have a hash key on the `Cats` collection so if you do `db.cats.findOne();` it'll look like the following:

```
> db.cats.findOne();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f248f8ae4b0b775c9eb002d"),
    "metaData" : {
        "type" : "cute",
        "id" : "4ed3b6c599114b488be52bc3"
    },
        ....
}
```

I query very often (using Mongoid), with something like this:

`Cat.first(:conditions => { "metaData.id" => an_id }`

I'd really like to be able to take advantages of indexes here, but I'm not entirely sure if I should index all of metaData or just metaData.id (I query against id specifically, and very often).

Would love any solution to this problem because I think I can dramatically speed up queries if I do the right thing here. Also, this is a unique index.

also metaData is not an embedded document. it does not have its own collection. it is simply a hash with a 1:1 mapping in each cats object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just define an index on the embedded document.  This is covered here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-UsingDocumentsasKeys

For your specific example, this would be:

```
db.Cats.ensureIndex({ "metaData.id" : 1}, {unique : true})
```

To compare your results do some of your standard queries in the shell with a .explain() to compare the speed with and without the index.  If you are not doing a lot of queries you might need to hint the index to use so that it doesn't cache the "best" index (don't forget there is one on _id by default).  More explain info here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain